# Pull-push error while commiting

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Ssh (MergeConflict).
1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge

i tried git pull from Action command prompt, it says unidentified external or internal command.

each time i'm taking a clone from master database.if there are no pulls then everything works fine. I can push.

please help. i tried all possible solutions.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21921657/1585160

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge (pull is just fetch + merge) with uncommitted changes. You should either:

- commit your changes to the local branch, then pull
- stash, then pull, then unstash